# node vault is not able to initialize and gives me the error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8200

Tags: node.js

The error is as shown below:

```
{ RequestError: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8200
    at new RequestError (C:\Users\anand\quFlipApi\node_modules\request-promise\lib\errors.js:11:15)
    at Request.RP$callback [as _callback] (C:\Users\anand\quFlipApi\node_modules\request-promise\lib\rp.js:60:32)
    at self.callback (C:\Users\anand\quFlipApi\node_modules\request\request.js:188:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Request.onRequestError (C:\Users\anand\quFlipApi\node_modules\request\request.js:884:8)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:310:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1276:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)
  name: 'RequestError',
  message: 'Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8200',
  cause:
   { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8200
       at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
       at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1049:20)
       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1085:14)
     code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
     errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
     syscall: 'connect',
     address: '127.0.0.1',
     port: 8200 },
  error:
   { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8200
       at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
       at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1049:20)
       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1085:14)
     code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
     errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
     syscall: 'connect',
     address: '127.0.0.1',
     port: 8200 },
  options:
   { method: 'PUT',
     path: '/sys/init',
     json: { secret_shares: 1, secret_threshold: 1 },
     headers: { 'X-Vault-Token': undefined },
     uri: 'http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/init',
     simple: false,
     resolveWithFullResponse: true,
     callback: undefined,
     transform: undefined },
  response: undefined }
Connection with database succeeded.
```

The code for that is as shown below:
app.js

```
var options = {
    apiVersion: 'v1', // default 
    endpoint: 'http://127.0.0.1:8200' // default 
};

// get new instance of the client 
var vault = require("node-vault")(options);

// init vault server 
vault.init({ secret_shares: 1, secret_threshold: 1 })
    .then((result) => {
        var keys = result.keys;
        // set token for all following requests 
        vault.token = result.root_token;
        // unseal vault server 
        return vault.unseal({ secret_shares: 1, key: keys[0] })
    })
    .catch(console.error);
```

I have already removed clienttoken field to avoid any complexity, but still it is giving me the error.In this above code should I enter /remove any other field to make it work ?

Comment: Did you ever get this working? This is verbatim from their readme's getting started example. I get the same error. Did you post this on their github page?

Comment: `node-vault` maintainer here. This might sound too obvious, but are you running vault on that address? Do the REST API or the CLI work properly?